# shell script error expecting "do"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
while true ; do
echo "WTF"
done
```

This is giving a syntax error:
syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "do")

I also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
echo "WTF"
done
```

Comment: Both work fine for me. Try entering it through vi, as it may end up being some character encoding / line feeds in your script.

Comment: Weirdly your first attempt works find for me.  Perhaps your bash has a profanity filter :).  Any other info you can give us when your first one fails?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I suspect line endings.

Try:

```
hexdump -C yourscript.sh
```

And look for `0d 0a` sequences. You can strip `\r` (`0d`) with the `tr` command:

```
cat yourscript.sh | tr -d '\r' >> yournewscript.sh
```

Comment: I see 0d 0a sequences but your line to strip them out with the tr command didn't work for me. I used vi after that didn't work and its working fine now! thanks

Comment: No problem. If you are uploading the script to your linux/unix box via FTP, you can select ascii/text format, and FTP will handle the end of line conversion for you. If, on the other hand, you are creating the file some other way, tr is a good tool to strip unwanted characters.

Comment: @Jordan That command did not work for me if I tried to name the new script the same name as the old script. If you use a different name, delete the old file, then rename the new file to the old file name it will work.

Comment: This command worked for me as I had messed up the line endings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    echo "WTF"
done
```

Please pay special attention to the spaces in the line 'while [ true ]'

Comment: Ah, whoops... beat me to it.  ;)