# Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")

Tags: shell, syntax, sh, nohup

I have a very simple file, "retrieve4.sh"

Here is the full code:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
nohup php retrieve4.php 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup php retrieve4.php 2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

I keep getting the error

> Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you want an infinit loop?

Comment: This script looks dangerous. It forks as many php programs as it can, until you run out of processes.

Comment: Since the error message is not `command not found: 1`, and the whole wording does not look like a bourne/bash error message, you either have a command named *1* in your path, or the error message does not come  from the piece of code you posted. I guess you posted only an excerpt of the whole code. I think you also didn't post the full error message; at least bash also prints the line number (and the name of the script). In any case, please let us also know which shell you are using (and which version).

Comment: One more idea: Did you verify, that you have proper line endings, in particular in the `do` line?

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings in your script, so that `bash` sees `do\r` instead of `do`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should be an infinite loop try

```
while [ 1 = 1 ]
do
nohup php retrieve4.php 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup php retrieve4.php 2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

EDIT

```
while [ 1 ] 
do 
echo 'test' 
done
```

This is running perfectly well on my setup. Therefore I'd expect your method of running the script is wrong

You could also try something like this:

```
while true ; do php my_script.php ; done > /dev/null
```

Comment: It simply doesn't work. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: can you try to run a simple snippet without nohup? is it still not working then?

Comment: I need nohup. It is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Frankly though, even WITHOUT nohup, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It wasn't about removing nohop, but about testing if nohup is the problem or the shell itself

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491634/shell-script-error-expecting-do please tell us if this solves your problem

Comment: Your solution where you put it all on 1 line... that worked... Clearly, it was something to do with line formatting... It may be because I'm editing it on Windows and the server is Linux... Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Check if you have a file named `/dev/null\r` in your file system now.

Answer (score 1):

As per the above comment, you mentioned "I'm editing it on Windows and the server is Linux", the return carriage may be causing the issue.

Try a one-line solution to verify:

```
while true ; do php retrieve4.php ; done > /dev/null
```